# Create Lookup Field Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, lookup-column, column

I am using SharePoint 2013, I need to create a lookup field through PowerShell.

I tried this code but is not working:

```
$SiteUrl = "http://mySite" 
$WebObj = Get-SPWeb -identity $SiteUrl 
$myCustomList = $WebObj.Lists["newList"]
$ParentList=$WebObj.Lists.item("listTarget")
$myCustomList.Fields.AddLookup("NewLookupField",$ParentList.id,$false)  
$SPChildListLookupField = $myCustomList.Fields[$_.NameField]
$SPChildListLookupField.LookupField = $ParentList.Fields["fieldTarget"]
```

I want to lookup to a list on a custom field (not the default Title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved updating the field.

```
$SiteUrl = "http://mySite" 
$WebObj = Get-SPWeb -identity $SiteUrl 
$myCustomList = $WebObj.Lists["newList"]
$ParentList=$WebObj.Lists.item("listTarget")
$myCustomList.Fields.AddLookup("NewLookupField",$ParentList.id,$false)  
$SPChildListLookupField = $myCustomList.Fields[$_.NameField]
$SPChildListLookupField.LookupField = $ParentList.Fields["fieldTarget"]

//Added this line
$SPChildListLookupField.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line.

```
$myCustomList = $WebObj.Lists.item("newList")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it is not working :/

Comment: Does it throw an error? Is the field created at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**

Use below script to add Lookup field:

*Provide the List Id for the field xml property 'List'*

```
$Field_LookupList = $RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle('DemoListForLookup')
$clientContext.Load($Field_LookupList)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$Field_LookupList_Id = $Field_LookupList.Id


$fieldXml="<Field Type='Lookup'  DisplayName='"+ $Field_DisplayName +"' Required='"+$Field_Required+"'  StaticName='"+$Field_InternalName+"' Name='"+$Field_InternalName+"' List='"+$Field_LookupList_Id+"' ShowField='"+$Field_LookupListFields+"'/>" 
$spoList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXml,$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint)
$spoList.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```