# Link a list with a Doc Library

Tags: list, document-library, links-list

I have a unique identifier in my list and document library. Is there a way to create a lookup field or something of the sort that link the list item with the corresponding document in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to use some powershell script which will first create a lookup column in list (say A).

Then iterate through items in list A and query list B to for specified value. Add this value to lookup and update item.

Based on the number of items you can do performance upgrades to the script: store IDs of items from list B in cache to avoid querying for the same items twice (or more).

There is already a question/answer how to create lookup fields with powershell: [Create Lookup Field Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97521/create-lookup-field-powershell)